# Back when back button is pressed in webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

I have an Android app developed in Android Studio that works in webview. I want to go to the last file when back button is pressed from the phone's navigation bar. Here is what I have tried-

```
    private WebView myWebView;
   @Override
     public void onBackPressed(){
       if (myWebView.canGoBack()){
          myWebView.goBack();
         } else {
      super.onBackPressed();
      }
     }
```

But my app crashes when I press back. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);     
  if (webView.canGoBack()) {
    webView.goBack();
  }
  else {
    ......
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Does the else needs to be empty?

Comment: You can add your else condition if you're pressing back button on the first page. Example: You can add "exit confirmation dialog" if the back button is pressed on the homepage.

Comment: @Bibel Oli Thanks :) It did my job.